# Differences in ImageGenerator.flow_from_directory (class_mode)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a model to detect fire in road images with TensorFlow Keras. I loaded the training and validation data with Image Generator and achieved 97% and 92% accuracy respectively. However, when I try to test the model by only predicting, I get confusing results. My Test folder contains two subfolders corresponding to each of the two classes.

First I declared my test data generator like this:

```
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
```

Then I loaded my data into it in this way, using categorical class mode:

```
img_paths_test='Fire_roads_data\Test'
test_data_generator=data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        img_paths_test,
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        batch_size=100,
        class_mode='categorical')

predictions=my_new_model.predict(
            test_data_generator)
```

And when I decode the predictions, I get terrible results. My accuracy drops to less than 50%. Even by using data from the training folder it doesn't seem to get any better.

To decode them, I associate each of the elements in the resulting array to the images in the same way as my test_data_generator loaded them.

However, by changing how I load the data, removing the categorical class mode:

```
img_paths_test='Fire_roads_data\Test'
test_data_generator_2 = data_generator.flow_from_directory(img_paths_test,
                              classes=None,
                              class_mode=None,
                              shuffle=False,
                              target_size=(image_size, image_size))

predictions = my_new_model.predict_generator(test_data_generator_2)
```

my performance then becomes as expected, reaching 92% accuracy.

How can I explain this difference? It has nothing to do with the model itself.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is not that you removed the class mode but instead that you set `shuffle` to `False`.

Probably after predicting, you used `test_data_generator_2.classes` and those classes are not shuffled.